# locale definition with French republican calendar

Tags: date, locale

I wonder if it is possible to create a locale definition that would make the C library format the dates according to the French republican calendar.

I expect then, for example, run `date' and get something like "Sex Bru 5 11:43:51 CET 2012".

Comment: Maybe `strftime(3)` would help

Comment: @warl0ck I checked man 3 strftime, and I failed to see any reference to the French Republican calendar. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

No, the calendar is not something that may be customised with locales.

There's a [perl DateTime calendar module](http://search.cpan.org/~jforget/DateTime-Calendar-FrenchRevolutionary-0.10/lib/DateTime/Calendar/FrenchRevolutionary.pm) for the French Revolutionary Calendar though.

```
$ perl -MDateTime::Calendar::FrenchRevolutionary -le 'print DateTime::Calendar::FrenchRevolutionary->now->strftime("%c")'
Sex 06 Bru 0221 6:97:80
```